# Android elements background color issue

Tags: android, colors

I've got some problems with color schemes on my Sony XPERIA U (also known ST25i). In my android app in `layout.xml` I set bg color for 2 `Buttons` and `ImageView`: (this is fragmet of `layout.xml`)

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@+id/update_app_group_start"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/update_button_update"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                android:id="@+id/update_app_button_download"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:background="@color/my_light_blue"/>

        <ImageView android:layout_width="2dp"
                   android:layout_height="48dp"
                   android:background="@color/my_light_blue"
                   android:id="@+id/update_app_buttons_delimiter"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/update_button_cancel"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/my_white"
                android:id="@+id/update_app_button_cancel"
                android:background="@color/my_light_blue"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

and `colors.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <color name="my_white">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="my_light_blue">#33b5e5</color>
</resources>
```

However, in my `activity` background colors for these elements sets unpredictable : sometimes yellow, red or green colors. If I set them directly in code in such manner :

```
    final ImageView delimiter = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.update_app_buttons_delimiter);
    delimiter.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.my_light_blue));
```

and it works fine.

Have any one issued this problem? Also, I using `ActionBarSherlock` and `ViewPagerIndicator`.

Thanks for responses!

Comment: Haven't seen this issue. Do you still face this issue? Have you found a solution?